# Difference between arrays and pointer when expression such as anArray++ is used in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm currently studying C using the book "C Primer Plus 6th edition.

In the chapter on arrays and pointers, the author states

> As far as C goes, the two expressions ar[i] and *(ar+i) are equivalent
>   in meaning. Both work if ar is the name of an array, and both work if
>   ar is a pointer variable. However, using an expression such as ar++
>   only works if ar is a pointer variable.

I thought in c, `ar[0]` and `*(ar + 0)` is equivalent and they both equal to the value contained in index 0 of the array. But why expression such as `ar++` only works if `ar` is a pointer variable? I'm really stuck on the logic behind it.

Comment: You can modify what a pointer points to. Not so with the identifier representing an array. `ar++` requires an lvalue, which an array is *not*, but a pointer *is*. Directly related, it is the same reason `ar = <something>` doesn't work for arrays, but works for pointers.

Comment: Changing the 'base address' of an array is not allowed in C. Hence its does not work. See my answer.

Comment: There is a difference between and array and a pointer. This might sound obvious, but this is a common mistake done. Try doing sizeof on both. When you say array, it has meta about its complete size, knowing both the starting and ending address with its name pointing to base(start) . But pointer is just pointing to somewhere. Array names are constants and cannot be modified. Thus incrementing them is error. P. S. You can do this arr+1.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `arr` is an array and `arr++` works on it. So, what supposed to do? If it is incremented, now, where is the pointer into the first element of the array? Therefore, it does not make sense the value of an array, which is pointed to the first element of the array, could be incremented and it is not logical anymore.

On the other side, if `arr` is a pointer, it could be moved and set to other places. Therefore, it makes sense you can change the value of the pointer.

In sum, although this fact is true which the name of the array pointed to the first element of an allocated array, it does not make sense to be set or changed over time like a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

`ar++`

evaluates to

`ar=ar+1` this won't work for the array `ar[]` simply because an array once declared won't allow you to change its starting index permanently and that is indeed the primary difference between `*arr` and `arr[]`.

The fact that, for an array `ar[]`,  `ar[1]` and `*(ar+1)` works is because pointer type arithmetic or pointer notation can be used for an array and vice versa and both should produce the same code.

Answer (score 1):

ar++ increments the location of the pointer which points to the array. In general ar++ moves the pointer to the next element in the array.
after declaring the array the pointer points the first element or ar[0] initially. ar++ makes the pointer move to the next element or ar[1] and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`ar++` is equivalent to `ar = ar + 1.` So basically it is an assignment so by increment we are changing the base address of an array which is not allowed.